# Updating Arduino Uno R3 ATMega16u2 firmware

Tags: arduino, atmel, firmware

Regarding another big problem I have with some of my arduino's boards I start to suspect the ATMega16U2 chip to be corrupted and would like to be sure that he's working fine.

So I've download Atmel Flip and I'm able to connect to the ATMega16u2 through serial with the proper driver installed and the 16u2 passed in DFU mode.

But now I'm a bit stucked. Indeed on the github repository of the arduino project I can only find the 8u2 code. And I can't find any hex file firmware for the 16u2...

As it's the first time I'm doing this, can you help me a bit ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The firmware you are looking for is in the Arduino installation folder

For example if installed in the root of C
C:\arduino-1.5.5-windows\arduino-1.5.5\hardware\arduino\avr\firmwares\atmegaxxu2`

---

If you prefer an online link it can be found:
https://github.com/arduino/Arduino/tree/master/hardware/arduino/firmwares/atmegaxxu2

Comment: You got me while I was typing :-)

Answer (score 1):

I just find where they are.
Under the arduino installation folder : \hardware\arduino\firmwares\

In my case for the arduino uno R3 : \hardware\arduino\firmwares\atmegaxxu2\arduino-usbserial\Arduino-usbserial-atmega16u2-Uno-Rev3.hex